# Vuejs commit to a mutation fails

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

This is how am performing commit but data is never passed through

```
const actions ={
 updateBtn({commit}, data){
  commit("test", data);
  console.log("data is"+data);//data here has a value

 }
}


const mutations={
test(state, {data}){
    console.log(data) //this is always undefined.
  }

}
```

Where am i going wrong in the mutations

Comment: The issue is that you are [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the second argument in the `test` mutation via `{data}`. This means the function is expecting as its second parameter an object with a `data` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using like this without function parameter.

```
const actions = {
 updateBtn({commit}, data){
  commit("test", data);
  console.log({data}); // data here has a value

 }
}


const mutations = {
  test(state, data) {
    console.log({data});
    state.data = data;
  }
}
```